# How to add any text box after every 5 latest posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have updated 20 posts in wordpress theme. And i need to add my own text box after every 5 posts. So that i can add 4 text box after every 5 post. 
I think it can be done by `$post_counter` please any one give me a query for my question.

My code simply seems to,

```
<?php
query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>20,orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/baw-post-views-count/ (A plugin for counting the posts)

Comment: I dont need to count the post or view counts.. I need to add a text box after 5 posts simultaneously..

Comment: `$i = 0;` `echo $i % 5 == 0 ? '<input type="text"/>' : '';`

Comment: Well, but you have to count the posts, to add a textbox after 5 posts. Otherwise you dont know when u have to add the textbox.

Comment: i need this without a plugin @xatenev

Comment: where i need to use this code? @ohgodwhy could you please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read your comment and i updated @zameerkhan code.

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 20, orderby => post_date, order => desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
//this will create text box after 5 post with name mytext1,mytext2 etc.
<?php echo ($p%5 == 0) ? '<input type="text" name="mytext'.($p/5).'" />': "";
$p++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in your code.. I think "" not structured well..

Comment: wow, wow, wow, wow thank you thank you thank you so much.. This what i need.. Thank you @shivanshupatel and Thank you for zameerkhan.. Lot of thanks to you both buddy..

Answer (score 4):

I believe this is what you need

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page' => 20, orderby => post_date, order => desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php echo ($p%5 == 0) ? '<input type="text" name="mytext[]" />' : "";
$p++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: wow.. super it works like a charm. thank you @zameer khan.. i will mark this as a answer.. Also if i need different text box to add after every 5 posts, what i need to do???? Thank you once again

Comment: You just need to change the number (5 in this case). Eg. If you need a textbox after every 6 posts then make it 6 instead of 5.

Comment: Ya i understood. But my question is "For eg: If text box 1 seems after 5th post means, after that 5 posts (that is before 11th post) i need to show text box 2. So that the two text boxes are different.. I think you could understand what i am meaning??

Comment: No buddy your question is still not clear to me. Can you be a bit more precise? Or please share your code base.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use `query_posts`, forget that it exists or ever existed. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

**FROM THE CODEX ON `query_posts`**

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. query_posts() is overly simplistic and problematic way
>   to modify main query of a page by replacing it with new instance of
>   the query

Your code should look like this

```
$args = array(
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page'=>20,
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $p = 1;
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    //this will create text box after 5 post with name mytext1,mytext2 etc.
    <?php echo ($p%5 == 0) ? '<input type="text" name="mytext'.($p/5).'" />': "";
    $p++;
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting. But, I didn't pay attention to the query, I just concentrated on the question asked. Will edit my answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score -1):

From your code

```
<?php
query_posts( array('posts_per_page'=>20,orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php echo ($p%5 == 0) ? '<input type="text" name="mytext[]" />' : "";
$p++;
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Instead of `<input type="text" name="mytext[]"/>` i replace `<h3>This is First text box</h3>`

So, now my output is,
Title 1
Title 2
Title3
Title4
Title5

#### This is First text box

Title 6
Title 7
Title 8
Title 9
Title 10

#### This is First text box

Title 11
Title 12
Title 13
Title 14
Title 15

#### This is First text box

...
Here see that "This is First text box" returns 4 times. My question is, i need after Title 10 the text should display as "This is Second text box" and so on.. I think now its clear